# Windows search indexer pending count never reaches 0 and creates millions of registry events in 15 minutes

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, search-indexing

I have constantly running Windows Search Indexer, around 5% CPU on i7-12700. The pending count in the Settings/Searching Windows never goes below 4 thousands, and the indexer creates 90 million of registry events during 15 minute Process Monitor recording session.

I'm using OneNote, so I'd like to keep the indexer running, because OneNote complains otherwise.

What I'd like to know is whether it's normal for Search Indexer to make this amount of registry events in 15 minutes, and what can be done to complete the pending files count (which never goes below 4k).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.